# Stationary point in nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given I have following system of nonlinear ordinary differential equations:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-y+ax^3$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=x+ay^3$

I have to find all stationary points. When I solve the system by setting both equations to zero, I only find the trivial solution $x=0, y=0$.

Can you help me or offer hints on how to find the other solutions?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: perform a substitution and obtain a ninth order polynomial in say y.  Factor and determine that y=0 is a solution.  You are then left with taking the 8th root of a number...so think complex numbers.

Comment: This is true. Many complex numbers though but definitely feasible.

Comment: I assume you mean "not feasible". If so,  use the conjugate root theorem and the fact that all the roots lie on a circle...this proves, algebraically (0,0) is the only real solution (find the arg of the first one and count in quarters of a half circle - none can possibly be real).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no real solutions other than $(0,0)$. (Just draw the curves $y=ax^3$ and $x=-ay^3$ and see where they intersect.)

Comment: Thanks, you are right.